# Working with l10n contexts (_x etc)

Tags: translation, localization, l10n

Basic l10n from a .mo file generated out of PoEdit works fine.

But as soon as I introduce `_x`, or variants, the link breaks, because as best as I can tell, PoEdit, completely ignores the context, and does not generate the corresponding `msgctxt` line in the .po/.mo files.

`_x`, `_ex` and other variants are all added to the keywords, and PoEdit **is** finding and parsing `_x()` occurrences within my source code. It's just not capturing the context and it is not generating the `msgctxt` line in the resulting .po file.

What's the workaround (*other* than manually editing the .po or .pot file?)

Comment: Is this a WordPress issue, or something with POEdit? I've generated plenty of translation files from WordPress Plugins/Themes, but, as far as I know, none that use a translation context. Does this happen only in POEdit, or using other translation tools, as well?

Comment: Hey Chip, I hear you, and to be honest, I'm pretty sure this has nothing whatsoever to do with WordPress. So why post here, right? It's just that it seems like such a common issue in the WP community that someone must have come across it already. I hope you won't recommend removing the question as a result - I do think it's quite relevant to the WP SE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When adding _x to the keywords, try it this way:

_x:1,2c

This tells the parser to watch out for _x and to take the first argument as msgid and the second argument as a comment, which will then be recognized as context by poEdit and inserted as msgctxt.

Oddly enough, my poEdit then shows me the msgid twice in the "new/old" messages window. However, in the messagelist everysthing is correct then.

Comment: This is the right answer for the _x function but the author of the question named _ex too. Maybe you'd like to add some more information here. I find the post [WordPress – Poedit: Translation Secrets](http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/wordpress-poedit-translation-secrets/) very useful regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your poedit project settings, add _x to the keywords

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/translating-your-theme/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have specified in my original post that I AM adding _x, _ex and other variants to the keywords.